# How to get offset of upper left corner in current screen view in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I found out position of upper left corner of current screen? E.g. when I scroll down html document I need to calculate with mouse positions relative to start of document. I would like to calculate something like `mouseOffsetY = upperleftCorner.offset.y + event.clientY;`

Answer (score 1):

get scrollTop of body by `document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].scrollTop;`

so it will come:

```
mouseOffsetY =document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].scrollTop+event.clientY;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it will work only when scrollbars are present. But never mind.

Comment: It does not seem to be working. I used `console.log( $('body').get(0).scrollTop );` or `console.log( document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].scrollTop );` when I clicked on element down the page. Both printed 0. Scrollbars present.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in Firefox:

```
console.log( $('body').get(0).scrollTop );
console.log( document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop );
```

Because Firefox checks the html[0].scrollTop insteady body.

Finally it's safer to use

```
window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0
```

Works well in Firefox 48.

In Firefox this

```
  console.log( window.pageYOffset );
  console.log( document.documentElement.scrollTop );
  console.log( $('html').get(0).scrollTop );
  console.log( $('body').get(0).scrollTop );
  console.log( document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop );
```

Will print e.g.:

```
446
446
446
0
446
```